# How to force NPM packages to be required in lower case?

Tags: node.js, macos, filesystems, node-modules

We have a few Mac users on our team who sometimes accidentally capitalize a require statement, like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('Sequelize')
```

Instead of the 'normal' way:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
```

However, on MacOS the first way of doing it doesn't throw any errors or anything, I'm guessing because of the differences in file systems. However, when we deploy our code to cloud providers running linux it doesn't work because Linux handles file names differently and the capitalized version of the require statement fails.

Is there a way to "enforce" lower case requires when importing npm modules, so that even on Macs the application will throw an error? Is this a feature that is native to NodeJS or would it have to be a step in our build system to manually check the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in linting or you could just use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lower-case) module inside require brackets